# How do i set up google map in my template?

Tags: javascript, html, css

HI i am working with a template webpage. On my "contact" page, there is a google map, which loads on the page. How do i alter it and put the correct address in the code?

HTML:

```
 <!-- map -->
              <div class="onStep" data-animation="fadeIn" data-time="300" id="map-1"></div>
              <!-- map end -->
```

JS:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

                    function init() {
                        // Basic options for a simple Google Map
                        // For more options see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions
                        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-6.372251, 106.831649);

                      var mapOptions = {
                            // How zoomed in you want the map to start at (always required)
                            zoom: 15,
                            disableDefaultUI: true,
                            scrollwheel: false, 
center: myLatlng, // New York

                            // How you would like to style the map. 
                            // This is where you would paste any style found on Snazzy Maps.
                            styles: [{"featureType":"all","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"weight":"2.00"},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#fc0000"}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.country","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#f2f2f2"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"landscape.man_made","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":45}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#eeeeee"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#7b7b7b"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#46bcec"},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#c8d7d4"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#070707"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]}]
                        };

                        // Get the HTML DOM element that will contain your map 
                        // We are using a div with id="map" seen below in the <body>
                        var mapElement = document.getElementById('map-1');

                        // Create the Google Map using out element and options defined above
                        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: myLatlng,
                            map: map,
                            icon: 'img/map-marker.png',
                            title: 'Company'
                        });



                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample contact us page i made for my test project
you can try and implimet this.
it points to my company loaction
it has minimum HTML, CSS & JS and its very easy to understand and implement.

```
<?php include_once('header.php'); ?>
<div class="nav">
  <div class="nav-header">
    <div class="nav-title">
      <a href="user_home.php">Cart Home</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-links">
    <a href="function.php?type=logout">Logout</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <form name="contactUsForm" id="contactUsForm" method="post" action="function.php?type=contactUsMessage">
  <center><h3 class="title">Contact Us</h3></center>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="column1">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['name'])) echo $_POST['name']; ?>" required="required">

      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email ID" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])) echo $_POST['email']; ?>" required="required">

      <label for="message">Message</label>
      <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Write something" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['message'])) echo $_POST['message']; ?>" required="required" style="height:200px">
```

You're good to go!